# Is it possible for an environment variable to hold an array value in cloud foundry manifest?

Tags: yaml, manifest, cloud-foundry, pcf

I am trying to push an app into cloud foundry, and pass an array value via environment variable.
But I receive ***yaml: unmarshal errors:
line 7: cannot unmarshal !!seq into string
FAILED***

manifest.yml:

```
---
applications:
- name: my-app1     # A default name for Cloud Foundry to give your app
  memory: 128M         # The amount of RAM required for each instance
  disk_quota: 256M    # How much disk space the application needs
  no-route: true
  health-check-type: none
  buildpacks:
    - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack
  env: 
    countries: 
      - america
      - australia
      - japan
      - nertherland
```

please Note: I validated my yaml via online validators and it looks good.

Answer (score 3):

Environment variables are an operating system concept and are passed into your application. They must be strings.

You can encode arbitrary JSON, YAML or binary data with base64 encoding as your env var value.

Inside your app, you would decode the base64 into your original string (say JSON string) and the parse it into the data structure you want (an array of strings in your case)